# Different uname -a results

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, kernel

I am working on a multi-server system for a client. All of the servers are fresh installs (although two were installed a couple of months ago, five a couple of days ago).

They are all supposed to be the same version of everything, but when I uname -a the two that were installed originally have

```
3.2.0-36-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP GNU/Linux
```

and the five new ones have

```
3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP GNU/Linux
```

I have done apt-get upgrade on all servers, but this doesn't change. Is it a big deal? The servers will be a replicated mysql setup and the mysql version is the same on all of them.

Is it easy (or worthwhile) to upgrade the #46 to #57 so they are the same through and through? They are the same hardware. Can you point me to some guides as to how to do this upgrade?

Comment: you should really investigate deploying a configuration management system like Puppet if you're working on a multi-server environment. It will help eliminate headaches like this...

Answer (score 3):

> Different uname -a results

Are those servers have very different `uptime`?
My guess is that your running and installed kernels are out of sync. After installation of new kernel you should generally reboot the system for changes to take effect.

> They are all supposed to be the same version of everything

Don't assume - check!
To debug your problem further you should probably look into `/boot/` directory for list of available kernels and check loader configuration. Also check `dpkg -l|grep linux-image` output.

> Is it easy (or worthwhile) to upgrade the #46 to #57 so they are the same through and through?

To answer this question you should probably checkout changelog for you kernel package. This can be done for example via `apt-get changelog <package_name>`. But general recommendation is to always use latest kernel version provided by distrib's security team unless it introduces visible regressions for your workload.

**PS**. To upgrade system packages under Ubuntu one should use `apt-get dist-upgrade`
**PPS**. Also as suggested in comments if  you have more than one server it's usually a nice idea to use Chef/Puppet/Cfengine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do an apt-get update before you did your apt-get upgrade?  If so, you probably have different apt sources enabled on the newer machines.

Comment: I did, yes but I did both update and upgrade on all machines